# Problem with ~/.cache/upstart

Tags: 13.10, upstart, disk-usage, gnome-session

I'm not experienced at all with Ubuntu yet and I know there are lots of things I have to learn, but I'm kinda puzzled about this one.

I just got (suddenly after a reboot) a free disk space warning about only having 17MB of free disk space left. I know I don't have many things on my home folder - it's a fresh installation (installed Ubuntu 13.10 only about 2 months ago on my new SSD).

According to Disk Usage Analyzer there's a ~/.cache/upstart directory of size 46GB (out of 50.7GB dedicated to my /home folder). After searching there I realised it's the `gnome-session.log` file being 46GB big.

I have no idea what is this - except from a few things I just read around googling it. I don't try things that I don't know how to handle on the specific machine because I don't want to risk harming it these days, so I don't really know what should I do now.
Is it possible that I did something wrong causing it ? Is it safe to just delete that /upstart folder to free some disk space, or that could cause me more problems. Should I do something else ?

Sorry if it's something common but I couldnt find anything clear and reliable to help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're experiencing this bug [#1240848](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1240848).

I have never on that condition. But, I'm sure It is safe to delete this dir (or just delete file(s) that's very big). You can also backup them if not so sure.

Try `sudo apt-get purge logrotate` then `sudo apt-get install logrotate`. If this not fixing the problem, then it is possible one of your application (or package) affecting it.

Many people say that it is periodically occured.

Comment: if I try to purge `logrotate`, it will also try to the following packages: `logrotate* ubuntu-standard*`, so I will not attempt this at all....

Comment: Well, that's pretty awesome (I mean **dangerous**!)..

Answer (score 3):

The log file gets bigger and bigger as it keeps appending to itself some recurring problem. First, identify the log file in the directory .cache that is growing in size using baobab (Disk Usage Analyzer), then open the log file using gedit and try to identify what is causing the problem. In my case it was one of the Startup Applications that was looking for a keyboard input, and was continuously writing to the log file since it wasn't getting that input. So in my case I editted the startup applications list and solved my problem.

Deleting the log file is an option, but it may not solve the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was caused by an outdated python ssl library, I updated it by using this command from home directory:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/python-cryptography_1.7.1-2_amd64.deb && wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/python-openssl_16.2.0-1_all.deb && sudo dpkg -i --auto-deconfigure python-cryptography_1.7.1-2_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i  python-openssl_16.2.0-1_all.deb
```

The original thread and discussion of the issue [is here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/447828)